# How to add a fade-in effect in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to add a fade-in effect when clicking on a div. I have a profile menu dropdown and the click event was made with jQuery. Also, how to make this to close if I click anywhere outside?

This is the code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".profile_link_header").click(function(){
        jQuery(".dropdown").toggleClass("active");
    })
});
```

CSS

```
.dropdown.active{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I managed to make it fade-in and fade-out but now I need to make it to auto toggle-off when clicking anywhere outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your html code, you just add fade-in on your selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".profile_link_header").click(function(){
        $(".dropdown").toggleClass("active").fadeIn("slow");;
    })
});
```

I suppose here is on your .dropdown class, else you apply the faeIn on your selector desired

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I managed to make it fade-in but when clicking to toggle out it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I managed to make it as I wanted, fadeIn and toggle off on click outside following this code from another question.

http://jsfiddle.net/evGd6/2/